# Difference between using slug_url_kwargs and pk_url_kwargs for get_object()

Tags: django

Difference between using slug_url_kwargs and pk_url_kwargs for get_object()
When would i use one over the other?

```
from django.urls import path
from books.views import AuthorDetailView

urlpatterns = [
    #...
    path('authors/<int:param>/', AuthorDetailView.as_view(), name='author-detail'),
]
```

For the above example, would pk_url_kwargs = 'param' be sufficient?
When would i use the slug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For the above example, would `pk_url_kwargs = 'param'` be sufficient?

**Yes**. It will search in your model for an object with as primary key `pk`, the `param` in your url.

> When would I use the slug?

The [Django glossary](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/glossary/#term-slug) describes a *slug* as:

> A short label for something, containing only letters, numbers, underscores or hyphens.

It is what you often see in an url of a *content management system (CMS)*, like:

```
https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2008/apr/12/spring/
https://www.myblog.com/this-is-the-title-of-an-article
```

You can add a [**`SlugField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.SlugField) or an [**`AutoSlugField`** [readthedocs.io]](https://django-autoslug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html#autoslug.fields.AutoSlugField) from the [**`django-autoslug`** package [GitHub]](https://github.com/justinmayer/django-autoslug/) to store a slug. The slug is normally constructed based on the content of a field (like the `title` of a `Book`, the `name` of an `Author`, etc.).

The [**`DetailView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) will then filter the field specified by the [**`slug_field`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.slug_field) on the content in the url specified by the [**`slug_url_kwarg`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.slug_url_kwarg). These both have as default `'slug'`. You thus can specify in your url something like:

```
path('authors/<slug:slug>/', AuthorDetailView.as_view(), name='author-detail'),
```

Given of course your model (`Author` has some sort of slug field).

Comment: Grateful for you Willem always a lot of effort into your answers, thank you!